# how to get data of 3 columns into one using case statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table with firstname, middlename, lastname. I want to add these 3 column data into one as fullname as if middlename != '' then fullname = firstname middlename and if lastname != '' then fullname = firstname middlename lastname.
I tried as follows but no row is affected.

```
UPDATE studentprofiles SET fullname = CASE middlename WHEN middlename !=  '' THEN firstname +  ' ' + middlename ELSE firstname END WHERE fullname = ''
```

How to do this? I have to update multiple rows. Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved as follows:

```
UPDATE studentprofiles 
    SET fullname = CASE
                WHEN middlename != '' AND lastname != '' THEN concat(firstname,' ',middlename,' ',lastname)
                WHEN middlename != '' AND lastname = '' THEN concat(firstname,' ',middlename)
                WHEN middlename = '' AND lastname != '' THEN concat(firstname,' ',lastname)
                ELSE concat(firstname)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an `AND` like this:

```
CASE
WHEN middlename != '' AND lastname != '' THEN firstname + middlename + lastname
ELSE ''
END AS fullname
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply concatenate the columns data like

```
UPDATE studentprofiles 
SET fullname = concat(firstname, middlename, lastname);
```

**EDIT:** In that case you can use `IFNULL()` function like

```
UPDATE studentprofiles 
SET fullname = IFNULL(firstname,'') +
               IFNULL(middlename, '') +
               IFNULL(lastname, '');
```

Comment: but i have to check for empty value in middlename and lastname. The value is not to be added in fullname if empty. That's why I need case.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this :

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

check this link for more information 
  [enter link description here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)